# Checking whether client locale is in the list of supported languages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I want to present the website to the users in their preferred language in the case that the website supports that language.**

In Spring Boot, I use the following bean to set the default language for the client:

```java
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setLocaleAttributeName("user_locale"); // Not strictly needed
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return localeResolver;
}
```

How could I modify it to take the client's language, and check whether it is in the list of supported languages, e.g.

```java
private List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(new Locale("en"), new Locale("de"), new Locale("fr"), new Locale("sp"), new Locale("it"));
```

and then set the locale using something like

```java
return locales.contains(locale) ? locale : Locale.ENGLISH;
```

Notice that this should happen every time a session is initiated.

Comment: How do you pass a locale into the backend? Does the fronted do this, or are you referring to the HTTP header `Accept-Language`

Comment: I am referring to HTTP header, Spring Boot default way of handling locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the locale depending on the HTTP header `Accept-Language` you need to use `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`, for example:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    var resolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    resolver.setSupportedLocales(
            List.of(Locale.ENGLISH,
                    Locale.FRENCH,
                    Locale.of("es"))
    );

    return resolver;
}
```

It's easy to set up and I guess that's exatly what you want.

The next step is to get exatly the locale that is defined using `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` and use it, for example, to get a message from the message sources. To do this you can use `LocaleContextHolder` as follows:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor;

@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getGreeting() {
    String msg = messageSourceAccessor.getMessage("msg", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(msg);
}
```

}

You can visit my [github](https://github.com/elimxim/ex-spring-boot-greeting) where I created a working example. To test the locale I used the [Locale Switcher Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the currently stored Locale like this:

```java
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale);
```

A good way, if cookies are allowed, would be to implement it like that:

```java
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver("BALLROOM_LANGUAGE");

    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale);

    return localeResolver;
}
```

There is no need to check whether the automatically requested clients language is in your list, since it would always fallback to your default message implementation (which in your case would be english).

One way to let the user change the locale manually (what should always be possible) would be a custom LocaleController:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/locale")
public class LocaleController {

    @PostMapping(path = {"", "/"}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public String locale(@RequestParam("locale") String locale,
                         HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) {

        if (locale != null && !locale.isBlank()) {
            LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
            if (localeResolver == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found");

            try {
                localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocale(locale));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.debug("Ignoring invalid locale value [{}]: {}", locale, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
        return referer != null && !referer.isBlank() ? "redirect:" + referer : "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

You would simply send a post request containing the desired locale as String in form of e.g. `en_US`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I do not quite understand how the defaulting mechanism based on the supported languages list is achieved in this answer. If the language is supported (like Spanish), then it should NOT default (to English). And this should happen every time someone opens a session. That was my primary problem with `localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale);` in Bean.
`.

Comment: If, for example, the broswer sends `es_ES` as the preferred locale, then Spring Boot sets this locale into the LocaleContextHolder. What you now have to do is to make sure, that wherever you want to get your app i18ned, you have spanish options in place. Spring Boot (respectively Java) will then automatically try to get spanish versions of whatever. This can be used to format dates and times or display text content, which you have stored inside `messages.properties`: you then have the base `messages.properties` and the supported languages `messages_en.properties` and `messages_es.properties`.

Comment: If you set the locale manually via `localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale)` then this is the locale which Spring Boot uses when trying to resolve the locale for e.g. validation messages. You still have to provide the support for the locale (language), e.g. spanish validation messages, otherwise Spring uses fallback options. Setting up the locale alone is not sufficient, you must also provide support. Spring then knows what you want and will automatically try to find the desired messages.